# Am I doing unit testing wrong, my unit tests seem unnecessary given that the integration tests will actually show the real results

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, nestjs

I'm currently using NestJS as a framework and the tests are written are executed using Jest. My issue right now is that the unit tests that I write seem very simple and due to having to mock the database I don't really test what the database would actually do. Let me elaborate:
Given that I have a `UserService` which would look like so:

```js
@Injectable()
export default class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly userRepository: UserRepository) {}

  public async getUserById(id: number): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.byId(id);

    if (!user) {
      throw new UserNotFoundByIdError(id);
    }

    return user;
  }

  public async deleteUserById(id: number): Promise<void> {
    const user = await this.getUserById(id);

    await this.userRepository.deleteUser(user);
  }
}
```

The Repository implementation would be like so:

```js
@Injectable()
export default class UserRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private readonly repo: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  public byId(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return this.repo.findOne({ where: { id }});
  }

  public async deleteUser(user: User): Promise<User> {
    await this.repo.delete(user.id);
  }
}
```

The unit tests would be located in the `tests/unit` folder and be as follows. Ignore the `createMockInstance` it just creates a anonymous object which has every method that the provided class has but mocked.

```js
const userRepositoryMock = createMockInstance(UserRepository);
const userService = new UserService(userRepositoryMock);

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
  jest.resetAllMocks();
})

describe('UserService', () => {
  describe('getUserById', () => {
    it('should return the provided user from the repository', async () => {
      (userRepositoryMock.byId as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({...new User(), id: 1}))

      const user = await userService.getUserById(1);

      expect(user).toBeDefined();
      expect(user.id).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('should throw a UserNotFoundByIdError if the repository returns a false value', async () => {
      await expect(() => userService.getUserById(1)).rejects.toThrow(UserNotFoundByIdError)
    });
  });

  describe('deleteUserById', () => {
    it('should delete the user fromt he database', () => {
      (userRepositoryMock.byId as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({...new User(), id: 1}));

      await userService.deleteUserById(1);

      expect(userRepositoryMock.deleteUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should throw a UserNotFoundByIdError if the user does not exist', async () => {
      await expect(() => userService.deleteUserById(1)).rejects.toThrow(UserNotFoundByIdError)
    });
  });
});
```

Here is how the integration tests would look like, not that I have omitted the create user function to shorten the question.:

```js
let app: INestApplication;
let userService: UserService;
let userRepository: UserRepository;

beforeAll(async () => {
  const testModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
      databaseProvider,
      UserModule,
    ],
  }).compile();

  app = testModule.createNestApplication();

  userService = app.get(UserService);
  userRepository = app.get(UserRepository);
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  // clear database...
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await app.close();
});

describe('UserService', () => {
  describe('getUserById', () => {
    it('should return the provided user from the repository', async () => {
      const createdUser = await userRepository.createUser({ name: 'foo' });

      const user = await userService.getUserById(createdUser.id);

      expect(user).toBeDefined();
      expect(user.id).toEqual(createdUser.id);
    });

    it('should throw a UserNotFoundByIdError if the repository returns a false value', async () => {
      await expect(() => userService.getUserById(1)).rejects.toThrow(UserNotFoundByIdError)
    });
  });

  describe('deleteUserById', () => {
    it('should delete the user fromt he database', () => {
      const createdUser = await userRepository.createUser({ name: 'foo' });

      await userService.deleteUserById(createdUser.id);

      await expect(() => userService.getUserById(createdUser.id)).rejects.toThrow(UserNotFoundByIdError);
    });

    it('should throw a UserNotFoundByIdError if the user does not exist', async () => {
      await expect(() => userService.deleteUserById(1)).rejects.toThrow(UserNotFoundByIdError)
    });
  });
});
```

The reason that the integration tests directly start from the service layer is because the design I'm taking only passes along the data to the service classes and does nothing else. If the upper layer has to do more functionality then I create a separate service which handles the more complex logic thus resulting in the tests just starting a layer upward without there really being any functionality there.

The unit tests in this scenario seems very unnecessary given that it plays with mocked entities and that the structure is very simple. It is progressively becoming more annoying to write the unit tests due to them being mostly boilerplate and testing little to no logic.
Am I missing something here or am I even looking at the issue the right way?

Comment: Is your question effectively, "my integration tests appear to validate all the behavior in my unit tests, so why should I write both?"

Comment: Pretty much yeah.

Comment: Write tests that give you value. If all of the behavior is captured in integration tests, there's no need to write unit tests too. I actually don't write a ton of unit tests. "Write tests. Not too many. Mostly integration." https://kentcdodds.com/blog/write-tests